# Optimize a join that uses a 50 character string as key - SAS SQL

Tags: sql, performance, join, sas, substr

I'm attempting a left join between a small table of only 8,000 rows and one with at least several million using email address as the key.  The 8,000 row table has email as a 50 position string, the huge table has email as 255 positions.

I'm getting I/O errors - so - will it help if I use substr on the long email address to get it down to 50 positions (the same as the other table) or will it make no difference in the join?

If it makes sense, then do I need to use two SQL steps - one to create the new variable and another to do the join using that created variable as the key?  Do I need to use some kind of length or formatting statement in addition to just something like substr(old_email, 1,50)?

Comment: Is your big table indexed in any manner?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I would doubt on email

Comment: Ok, are both datasets SAS datasets or is any data on a non SAS server, ie SQL/Oracle? Do you know if you can use Pass Through?

Comment: The smaller is SAS, the larger is db2.

Comment: Do you have the ability to create a temporary table in DB2?  If so, load the SAS table there and run the query on the DB2 server. Most likely the problem is SAS trying to download the full table from DB2 inside PROC SQL.

Comment: Heck, if you can't do that, put all of the email addresses from the 80 table into a few macro variables and pass the `SELECT whatever FROM big_table WHERE email_Address in (&macvar1 &macvar2...)` to DB2 - you can probably put ~2000 to 3000 email addy's into each macro variable at least (quoted of course).  Probably better than downloading the whole table.  And just for fun, if you make it a right join is it any better, out of curiousity?

Comment: http://support.sas.com/kb/39/605.html Use macro variables to feed the email list to your query so that it cuts down the processing. A single macro variable has a 64k character limit so either create multiple macro variables or use the solution in the link included.

Comment: What does that code look like to create a temporary table in DB2?  Is that actually run from within the SAS environment?

Comment: You might be getting I/O errors because `substr()` may not necessarily translate in db2. In those cases, SAS will do a `select *` and pull everything down to the server, then do the filtering and joining. In general, it's better to take the simplest filter you need, pull the data to the SAS server's WORK directory, then join the tables. You can confirm if this is the case by using `options sastrace=',,,d';` You will see errors about the SAS server performing the processing if SAS can't translate a function into DB2.

Comment: @Reeza That sounds like an answer.